# How to apply or condition in filter in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list of `Int` and I want to filter the list with the help of or statement.

For example :

```
var a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to filter list based on `_ % 3 == 0` or `_ % 2 == 0`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a.filter(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 2 == 0)
```

Note that, when you refer to a lambda's argument more than once in the expression body, you can no longer use the `_` notation.

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> a.filter(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 2 == 0)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Sorry for that comment ... Its working.. actually i was trying with _ notation thats why m getting the problem. Thaks for quick reply. :)

Comment: @MahekShah No problem. Each time you type `_`, you're referring to a different argument. So `_%3==0 || _%2==0` is equivalent to `(x, y) => x%3==0 || y%2==0`

Answer (score 1):

Consider also a for comprehension as follows,

```
for (x <- a if x % 3 == 0 || x % 2 == 0) yield x
```